# Multithreaded Jsoup proxy authentication?

Tags: java

I want to connect multiple instances of JSoup with different proxies.

Any Idea on how I could do that?

I tested `System.setProperty` (setting all parameters: ip, port, user and pass), and that works, but, that kind of defeats the whole purpose of multithreading.

I tried setting only username and password with System.setProperty (so I could just add `.proxy(ip, port)` to existing jsoup connections), but that doesn't work.

I researched with the aid of official Java docs about `Proxy`, but the documentation was not very clear about this either.

Is there a way, without using `System.setProperty`, to use authenticated proxies with JSoup?

Comment: Ever get an answer to this question? have exact same issue